# What is "sepdflatexmk"?

Tags: makefile

A colleague gave me a `.tex` file and said it needed to be compiled with `sepdflatexmk`, which she had on her Mac. She didn't know anything more about this compiler. I did some Googling and it seems specific to TeXShop on Macs, relating to makefiles (about which I know essentially nothing). My questions:

1. What exactly is `sepdflatexmk`?
2. I have a Windows machine running TeXLive- is there something comparable to this compiler for Windows pc's? I looked in the `bin` folder and didn't see anything promising.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me expand on that answer. TeXShop ships with several engines based on the use of the base latexmk program. The pdflatexmk engine uses pdflatex as the typesetting engine without enabling shell-escape. The sepdflatexmk engine adds the shell-escape flag to pdflatex.

Comment: So it should be seen as a setting (engine call) in Texshop not something a user should expect to be able to call on the command line. That different is quite important. Not much of this discussion made it clear what an engine is in this context and it might confuse visitors. An I right in assuming that an "engine" in this context may be seen as a build rule, such that pdflatexmk might be the same as `latexmk -pdf` on the command line

Comment: @dalif: It is a shell script with additional configuration files used by TeXShop, not an external program.

Comment: I have a Windows machine and use TeXnicCenter as my editor. I accomplished the same thing, I presume, using an output profile calling `latexmk.exe` (after installing the `latexmk` package) and passing the arguments `-pdf -pdflatex="pdflatex -shell-escape"  "%wm"` to the compiler. The `-shell-escape` part is important, equivalent to the `se` portion of the `sepdflatexmk` name.

Comment: @GregH: that's pretty much it but the engines for TeXShop contain additional configuration files for processing files for some popular packages as well as more parameters passed to pdflatex to enable synctex, help latexmk, etc.

Answer (score 3):

From http://macosx-tex.576846.n2.nabble.com/eps-to-pdf-conversion-td7580188.html

> I would create an engine, sepdflatexmk, that is essentially identical
>   to the pdflatexmk engine but includes the --shell-escape flag. That
>   way you can use pdflatex with the --shell-escape flag set when you
>   need it and other engines if you don't need it. I.e., only use the
>   flag with ``trusted'' documents.
>
> Good Luck,
>
> Herb Schulz

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of TeXShop contain updated `latexmk` engines that allow you to set up shell-escape using TeXShop's `parameter` directive. See the documentation and installation instructions in `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/Inactive/Latexmk`. (Note: you can open `~/Library/TeXShop` by using the `TeXShop->Open ~/Library/TeXShop` Menu Item and go from there.)